# How to add multiple row's dynamically in DataGridTextColumn in wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

```
  DataGridTextColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn();
  col.Header = "SMS_Message";
  Binding bind = new Binding();
  bind.Source = (I_Want_To_Bind_New_MSG_All_the_Time);
  col.Binding = bind;

GridView.Columns.Add(col);
```

- I create column in datagrid Dynamically But now want to put different data on each row.
- Above code I want to bind new Message on every row all the time, how this is possible.

Comment: Can anybody answer this?

Answer (score 0):

Create proper `class`, object of which can be used as `DataContext / ItemsSource`.

If property types or number of properties changes, then use `Anyonymous Object`.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable replay.. but I am new in programming, would you like to give me example?